# Make the popup keyboard go away on the Note 9 For Chessbase

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note

[image]

Please make this popup stick to the bottom. It's going to give me a heart attack.

Comment: Going to add a bounty soon...

Answer (score 0):

Its called Floating keyboard, found in the game tools.. drove me nuts for about an hour... turn that feature off under Additional features and problem solved for me on my Galaxy Note9